# jQuery Ajax to update DIV

Tags: jquery

In My editStatus.jsp I have the following code that displays the total .
Now my requirement is to refresh total value every 5 seconds

```
<div id = "refreshDIV" class = "span3">
        ${total}
 </div>
```

The code to refresh the above DIV "refreshDIV" every 5 seoncds is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(refreshDiv, 5000); 
});

function refreshDiv(){
$.ajax({
  url: 'editStatus.jsp',

 }).done(function() {
   //Update my DIV from editStatus.jsp
 });
}
```

**From above code please let me know how do i update my DIV "refreshDIV" from refrshDiv function**

**also please let me know if the URL use in ajax is right the current page url editStatus.jsp ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just get the returned data from the ajax call and insert it into the element :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(refreshDiv, 5000); 
});

function refreshDiv(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'editStatus.jsp'
    }).done(function(result) {
        $('#refreshDIV').text(result);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks , please tell me more on result variable ? where does it come from ? how do I set it up

Comment: it's callback function .Result is the output provided from editStatus.jsp file

Comment: Ok but I dont have result variable in editStatus.jsp, 
<div id = "refreshDIV" class = "span3">
        ${total}
 </div> 
Is from editStatus.jsp only 
So how do I use result ? I dont have it on editStatus.jsp

Comment: Any output from the jsp file will be returned in the result variable, and then that output will be appended to the element? Did you just try it!

Answer (score 0):

Change your function like this:

```
function refreshDiv(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'editStatus.jsp',
        data: {
        },
        beforeSend:function(){},
        success:function(data){
            $('#refreshDIV').html(data);
        },
        error:function(){}
    });
}
```

Just make sure that the jsp returns some valid html.

Some other advantages using this, can be to show maybe a loading message before sending the request like this:

```
beforeSend:function(){
  $('#refreshDIV').html('Loading...');
}
```

You can do the same in the `error`  if an error is retrieved from the jsp.

Comment: what should I pass in data: ?

Comment: `data` is the html returned from the jsp when returning from the AJAX call

Comment: see when data is the html returned from jsp then do I need to have editStatus.html page ?